# How would you explain Javascript Typed Arrays to someone with no programming experience outside of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays

I have been messing with Canvas a lot lately, developing some ideas I have for a web-based game. As such I've recently run into Javascript Typed Arrays. I've done some reading for example at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) and I just can't understand anything I'm finding. It seems most often, when someone is explaining Typed Arrays, they use analogies to other languages that are a little beyond my understanding.

My experience with "programming," if you can call it that (and not just front-end scripting), is pretty much limited to Javascript. I do feel as though I understand Javascript pretty well outside of this instance, however. I have deeply investigated and used the Object.prototype structure of Javascript, and more subtle factors such as variable referencing and the value of `this`, but when I look at any information I've found about Typed Arrays, I'm just lost.

With this frame-of-reference in mind, can you describe Typed Arrays in a simple, usable way? The most effective depicted use-case, for me, would be something to do with Canvas image data. Also, a well-commented [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be most appreciated.

Comment: I'm also interested to see how Typed Arrays might be compared to multi-dimensional arrays like `array[x][y]`.

Comment: The closest data structure (but not as flexible) would be [`struct` in `C`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In typed programming languages (to which JavaScript kinda belongs) we usually have variables of fixed declared type that can be dynamically assigned values.

With `Typed Arrays` it's quite the opposite.

You have a fixed chunk of data (represented by `ArrayBuffer`) that you do not access directly. Instead this data is accessed by **views**.  Views are created at run time and they effectively declare some portion of the buffer to be of a certain type.  These views are sub-classes of `ArrayBufferView`.  The views define the certain continuous portion of this chunk of data as elements of an array of a certain type.  Once the type is declared browser knows the length and content of each element, as well as a number of such elements.  With this knowledge browsers can access individual elements much more efficiently.

So we dynamically assigning a type to a portion of what actually is just a buffer.  We can assign multiple views to the same buffer.

From the [**Specs**](https://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/):

```
Multiple typed array views can refer to the same ArrayBuffer, of different types,
lengths, and offsets. 

This allows for complex data structures to be built up in the ArrayBuffer.
```

As an example, given the following code:

```
      // create an 8-byte ArrayBuffer
      var b = new ArrayBuffer(8);

      // create a view v1 referring to b, of type Int32, starting at
      // the default byte index (0) and extending until the end of the buffer
      var v1 = new Int32Array(b);

      // create a view v2 referring to b, of type Uint8, starting at
      // byte index 2 and extending until the end of the buffer
      var v2 = new Uint8Array(b, 2);

      // create a view v3 referring to b, of type Int16, starting at
      // byte index 2 and having a length of 2
      var v3 = new Int16Array(b, 2, 2);

The following buffer and view layout is created:
```

[image]

> This defines an 8-byte buffer b, and three views of that buffer, v1,
>   v2, and v3. Each of the views refers to the same buffer -- so v1[0]
>   refers to bytes 0..3 as a signed 32-bit integer, v2[0] refers to byte
>   2 as a unsigned 8-bit integer, and v3[0] refers to bytes 2..3 as a
>   signed 16-bit integer. Any modification to one view is immediately
>   visible in the other: for example, after v2[0] = 0xff; v2[1](https://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/) = 0xff;
>   then v3[0] == -1 (where -1 is represented as 0xffff).

So instead of declaring data structures and filling them with data, we take data and overlay it with different data types.

Answer (score 1):

I spend all my time in javascript these days, but I'll take a stab at quick summary, since I've used typed arrays in other languages, like Java.

The closest thing I think you'll find in the way of comparison, when it comes to typed arrays, is a performance comparison. In my head, Typed Arrays enable compilers to make assumptions they can't normally make. If someone is optimizing things at the low level of a javascript engine like V8, those assumptions become valuable. If you can say, "Data will always be of size X," (or something similar), then you can, for instance, allocate memory more efficiently, which lets you (getting more jargon-y, now) reduce how many times you go to access memory and it's not in a CPU cache. Accessing CPU cache is much faster than having to go to RAM, I believe. When doing things at a large scale, those time savings add up quick.

If I were to do up a jsfiddle (no time, sorry), I'd be comparing the time it takes to perform certain operations on typed arrays vs non-typed arrays. For example, I imagine "adding 100,000 items" being a performance benchmark I'd try, to compare how the structures handle things.

What I can do is link you to: http://jsperf.com/typed-arrays-vs-arrays/7

All I did to get that was google "typed arrays javascript performance" and clicked the first item (I'm familiar with jsperf, too, so that helped me decide).

Comment: Good answer for not having any time! I think I'm seeing the problem I'm having understanding these. The functions shown in the jsperf are complete nonsense to me, so I am assuming that the problem is that I do not understand the underlying data structure. Example: I understand that the functions are traversing a grid/image-type structure, with a width and height (obviously). Normally though, I would store such a thing as a 2d array of objects like `image[x][y].property`, and so I don't understand what's being done with the `n` and `modulo`.

Comment: Yeah, in terms of jsperf, that is definitely a hard to understand one. I apologize for that, I didn't examine it closely. In fact, I would say my answer is sucky as well. Just googling, you'll dig up more explanations than I could ever hope to provide, in terms of differences. For example, this is another top hit on google (lots of jargon, but if you wade through, you might find some things stick, at least): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328658/are-the-advantages-of-typed-arrays-in-javascript-is-that-they-work-the-same-or-s